# How to replace the ag-grid sort arrow icon with my custom svg icon

Tags: angular

Appreciate if someone could help me out on this. BTW gone through the documentation but it’s not clear enough though

Answer (score 0):

> Example of creating custom svg: 
>   1. Inject MatIconRegistry and DomSanitizer in your constructor
>   2. Pass parameters to addSvgIcon method Param 1 : Pass custom name, Param 2 : Using DomSanitizer give your relative url to image.

```
    import {MatIconRegistry} from '@angular/material/icon';
    import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

    export class MyAppComponent {

    constructor(private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, private domSanitizer: 
    DomSanitizer) 
    {
      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon('my-custom-icon-name', 
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('../assetss/customImage.svg'))
    }

   }
```

> In your HTML file

```
    <button mat-icon-button>
       <mat-icon svgIcon="my-custom-icon-name" aria-hidden="false" aria- 
             label="Example home icon"></mat-icon>
     </button>`
```

> Why we need DomSanitizer here ? 
>   "By default, angular recognizes all the values as unsafe and automatically sanitizes it by removing the  tag but keeps the text content of the  tag as it is. Now the script will not run and the value is safe to insert into the DOM." [Reference link](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b)